# how can I upload any file with CLI with go?

Tags: go, proxy, command-line-interface, backend, httprequest

I wanna make a CLI program that can upload a CSV file so that later I can use the file uploaded as a payload to be proxied to the backend program?
Here is the scenario:

- get the path dir of the CSV file that will be uploaded and use it as the payload with CLI

```
    var payload = GenericPart{SourceId string, GenericFile string}
    var uploadGenericPartFileCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "upload",
        Short: "Upload generic part file",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            err := c.Client.UploadGenericPartFileCmd(payload.SourceId, payload.GenericFile)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            return nil
        },
    }

    uploadGenericPartFileCmd.Flags().StringVar(&payload.SourceId, "id-source", "", "Source ID")
    uploadGenericPartFileCmd.Flags().StringVar(&payload.GenericFile, "generic-file", "", "Generic File")`
```

- make a new request and proxy it to the predefined backend

```
   payload := &GenericPart{
       sourceId,
       genericFile,
   }

   requestBody, err := json.Marshal(payload)
   if err != nil {
       return fmt.Errorf("cannot make json, got %w", err)
   }

   req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf("%s/api/v1/upload", c.Url), bytes.NewReader(requestBody))

   resp, err := c.httpClient.Do(req)
   if err != nil {
       return fmt.Errorf("cannot make request to api service, got %w", err)
   }

   defer resp.Body.Close()
```

- the backend process the payload whose type is still a file (I already made a backend to process the uploaded file)

```
    source := request.FormValue("source_id")

    f, h, err := request.FormFile("data")
    if err != nil {
        c.httpError(writer, err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    fileType, _, err := mime.ParseMediaType(h.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    if err != nil || fileType != "text/csv" {
        c.httpError(writer, ec.NewError(ErrCodeCsvParse, Errs[ErrCodeCsvParse], fmt.Errorf("Content-Type `%s` is not valid", fileType)))
        return
    }

    reader := csv.NewReader(f)
```

can anyone tell me what should I add so I can use CSV file uploaded as a request to the backend?
And also I still have a bit confusion about how do I upload the file and use it as a payload? what should I do after I get the path dir?

many thanks!

Comment: Have you done any research? If so and you have a specific problem, edit your question to include more details and narrow down your question.

Comment: I edited it, pls kindly check who knows u can help

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the file with `os.ReadFile()` function and get `[]byte` data needed for the further request payload. Then add request header `Content-Type: text/csv` and send the request.

Let's say you run your code as: `$ go run main.go your_file.csv http://example.com/v1/upload`

Then your code could look similar to this:

```
data, err := os.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
...
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", os.Args[2], bytes.NewReader(data))
...
res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
```

P.S. I don't see the necessity of using 3rd party packages here.